# Getting "QFile::rename: Empty or null file name" when dropping file to QTreeView

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QSplitter of which :

- left side is Qtreeview for showing local system file using QFileSystemModel
- right side have QWebView with html page where I am showing directory and file name line by line returned by some API.

I want to make a drag and drop application. I have enable all the drag and drop required functions so it is working internally on its own view.

But I want to drag and drop between these two views, and when I am doing this, it's showing plus icon correctly, but when dropping the file, it is showing in the console :

> QFile::rename: Empty or null file name

Here's my code :

```
QStringListModel *model1 = new QStringListModel();
QStringList *stringList = new QStringList();
view2->setUpdatesEnabled(true);
view2->setAcceptDrops(true);


if(oldName == "" || CPE == "") {
    oldName = CPE;
} else {
    oldName = oldName + " / " + CPE;
}
view2->page()->mainFrame()->addToJavaScriptWindowObject("MainWindow",newMyJavaScriptOperations);

QString mypage;

QTextStream p(&mypage);

p << "<!DOCTYPE HTML>";

p <<"<html><head>\n<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'";
{width:350px;height:70px;padding:10px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;} </style>";
p << " href='webview.css' />\n";
p <<"<link href='file:///D:/QT/QT_JS/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>";
p << "<style type='text/css'>body { color:black }; </style>";
p<<"<script src='file:///D:/QT/QT_JS/selectCpe.js'></script>";
p << "<body ondragstart='return true'>";
p << "<ol class='breadcrumb'>";
if(CPE == NULL){
    qDebug()<<"CPE1";
    p << "<li class='active'>"<<cpeName<<"</li>";
}
else{
    qDebug()<<"CPE2";
    p << "<li><a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick = 'cpeContent()'>"<<cpeName<<"</a></li>";
    p << "<li class='active'>"<<oldName<<"</li>";
}
p<<"</ol>";
</div>";
p<<"<div class='row'>";
while(tmp!= NULL)
{


   if (tmp->isDir)
   {   
       p<<"<div class='col-lg-3'>";
       p<< "<a draggable='true'  width='336' height='69'       href='javascript:void(0)' onclick = 'openDir(this.id)' id="<< tmp->fileName<<">";
       p << "<img src='file:///D:/QT/QT_JS/manilla_gnome_fs_directory.png' class='logo'><br>";
       p <<"DirName: "<< tmp->fileName <<"</a></div>";
   }
   else
   {
       p<<"<div class='col-lg-3'>";
       p<< "<a href='javascript:void(0)' draggable='true'>";
       p << "<img src='file:///D:/QT/QT_JS/document_folder_blue.png' class='logo'><br>";
       float size = tmp->size/(1024*1024);
       p <<"FileName: "<< tmp->fileName <<"<br>"<<"Size: "<<size<<" MB</a></div>";
   }

   p<<"<br><br><br>";
   tmp = (fileNode_t *)tmp->next;
}
p<<"</div>";
if(head)
{
   qDebug()<<"display";
}
else
{
   p <<"No Contents...";
}
model1->setStringList(*stringList);

freeFileList(head);
head = NULL;
view2->setHtml(mypage);
view2->setAcceptDrops(true);
qDebug() << "In main2 method";
view1->hide();
//tree
qDebug() << "In main3 method";
QFileSystemModel *model = new QFileSystemModel;
model->setReadOnly(false);
QString dir("c:/sample");
model->setRootPath(dir);
tree->update();
tree->repaint();
tree->resize(1100, 550);
tree->setModel(model);
tree->setRootIndex(model->index((dir)));
tree->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::ExtendedSelection);
tree->setDragEnabled(true);
tree->setTextElideMode(Qt::ElideMiddle);
tree->viewport()->setAcceptDrops(true);
tree->setAcceptDrops(true);
tree->setDropIndicatorShown(true);
tree->setDefaultDropAction(Qt::CopyAction);
tree->setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView::DragDrop);
splitter->setAcceptDrops(true);
splitter->addWidget(tree);
splitter->addWidget(view2);
splitter->resize(1100, 550);
splitter->setWindowTitle("<- Local Files And api Files ->");
splitter->show();
```